# Cocoa (Swift) simulating a keyboard press

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am making a macOS App that should get some string from the server and then paste the string into the currently focused application. To achieve this I am using pasteboard and then simulating the CMD + V key press with CGEvent

```
func copyToClipboard(_ string: String) {
    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
    pasteboard.clearContents()
    pasteboard.setString(string, forType: .string)
}

func simulateCmdVKeyPress() {
    let source = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)

    // Command Key Down
    if let cmdKeyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: 0x37, keyDown: true) {
        cmdKeyDown.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
        cmdKeyDown.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    }

    // 'V' Key Down and Up
    if let vKeyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: true),
       let vKeyUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: false) {
        vKeyDown.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
        vKeyDown.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
        vKeyUp.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    }

    // Command Key Up
    if let cmdKeyUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: 0x37, keyDown: false) {
        cmdKeyUp.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1) // Small delay to ensure Command key state is cleared
    }
}
```

In Debug it works fine. But when I archive and extract the app, it stops working. Looks like some permission or entitlement is missing. In Release mode, it won't work either in Sandbox or without Sandbox. Please, help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [macOS: simulated mouse event only works when launching binary, not application bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843481/macos-simulated-mouse-event-only-works-when-launching-binary-not-application-b)

Answer (score 0):

I've found what was causing it. I was just running the release app from a different folder. This is impossible to grant the same accessibility permission for the same app in two different folders. So when you grant the accessibility permission to an app located in a specific folder, and then run the app with the same bundle ID from a different folder, the second one won't get the accessibility permissions and will never even ask for it.

Comment: Is it the folder or two instances of the app?

Comment: Looks like the folder, I never run two instances of the same app

Comment: @AharonZilberman Is your application code-signed? This sounds like the kind of confusion caused when you don't sign the application.